# Using org.apache.hadoop.yarn.logaggregation.filecontroller.ifile.LogAggregationIndexedFileController in C# azure function

Tags: c#, hadoop, azure-functions, hadoop-yarn

I am parsing  Spark executer Tfile format logs and I need to use org.apache.hadoop.yarn package in c# azure function. Is there any way to use it c# azure function? I am new to Azure functions and C#.

I feel for Java azure function I can use maven dependency
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Hadoop develop, we'd better use java. Azure function can run java either.

If you want to develop with c#, you can try with `Install-Package Microsoft.Hadoop.Client -Version 1.5.13` instead.